# Append JSON to another JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have two JSON objects which are Youtube API responses.

I want to append some part of the second JSON (source) to a particular position in the first JSON (destination) and finally have one merged JSON to send to view.

I've tried like so:

```
var merged = Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {

    destination.items[key].contentDetails = source[key].items[key].contentDetails;

})
```

They both contain same number of item sets so I use the same index key for destination within the loop of source and append each to the destination JSON.

`destination.items[key].contentDetails` is a valid reference that returns correct value in the console but when inside this loop it's undefined. 
What am I doing wrong here?
I'm not quite sure about this practice for such task so I'd greatly appreciate for some direction.

Comment: What's the downvote for and how this is off-topic? I'm not experienced with programming but trying to learn something here.

Comment: Sorry for all the downvotes! I think most people here are tired of newbies and need to take a walk. Could this be the answer to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498801/how-to-merge-two-json-objects-values-by-keys

Comment: or maybe you could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736590/add-new-attribute-element-to-json-object-using-javascript

Comment: are you sure that destination.items[key].contentDetails is undefined?
the weird  thing to me is that you use index key twice on the right side, maybe that's your problem

Comment: Don't worry and get used to it, on this site, people get downvoted without any reason. It sucks, but that's the way it is. About your problem, what is "wrong"? What's the intended result and what do you get instead?

Comment: @juraj I've used index twice for source because that's how that JSON is structured with nested array inside.

Comment: @juraj why so? No problem using `source["somekey"].items["somekey"].contentDetails`, as long as it's defined. Sub-keys can very well have the same name as their parent's.

Comment: @JeremyThille I know, but it seems weird :)

Comment: This question is an extension of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430504/merge-json-object-response-into-one-using-underscore-js  Which later on, I tried lodash _.extend but it merges like {a,b,c}, {a,b,c} while I want it to be {a,a}, {b,b}, {c,c} ... So here I was trying something different..which seems weird to me also but don't know what I can do to resolve.

Comment: try using Array.map https://jsfiddle.net/ym1npkg0/

Comment: FYI: you're dealing with objects ... json is a string notation of a javasacript object

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes..I'm aware of it..I was going to call it JSON object but wanted to simplify my wording. Thanks I was confused about this concept before :)

Comment: @juraj I will try Array.map as per your fiddle. Will update how I went. Thank you!

Comment: @juraj Array.map worked for me! I'm happy to accept your answer if you post one. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is because the `forEach` function returns `undefined`. The `forEach` method doesn't create a new object; it's used for iterating over an array and doesn't return any value. So, when you try to assign the result of `forEach` to `merged`, it becomes `undefined`.

To merge two JSON objects as you described, you can use a `for` loop or other methods like `map`. Here's a modified version of your code using a `for` loop to merge the two objects:

```js
for (var key in source) {
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        destination.items[key].contentDetails = source[key].items[key].contentDetails;
    }
}
```

This code iterates through the keys in the `source` object, checks if they exist in the `destination` object, and then merges the contentDetails accordingly.

Comment: Why not just keep the `forEach()` loop and get rid of assigning the result, since that's the only problem.